# Use SEE SQlite Encryption Extension in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, aes, system.data.sqlite

I'm creating an SQLite database with ADO.NET usyng System.Data.SQLite, now I need to encrypt it using AES-256.

I have access to SEE (SQLite Encryption Extension) and am looking on how to use it along with System.Data.SQLite.

Previously we used Devart to handle the extension and encrypt the database, but this is no longer possible.

I know that SEE is in c++, so I will have to use it with DLLimport. But I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a secure solution to your unencrypted `SQLite` database file,
you must use a library, which has encryption compiled into `SQLite` DB engine.
In this case contents of the file are en/decrypted on the fly by the engine.

There is an encryption module available here, but you have to compile it yourself:

http://www.iqx7.com/products/sqlite-encryption